# How to safely use $_GET['id'] to get details from database by selecting html table row

Tags: php, pdo, get, fetch

So, I have this working code to click on a link for showing details from one row of a database on another page in input text boxes.:

```
    <?php
            foreach ($allCentrifuge as $list) {
                $id = $list['id'];
                ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $list['experiment'] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $list['project_name'] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $list['project_date'] ?></td>
                    <td><a href="../Views/user_centrifuge.php?id=<?php echo $list['id']?>">Details</a></td>
                </tr>
                <?php
            }
            ?>
```

And this function to get those details:

```
    public function fetchCentrifuge()
    {

        $uid = $_GET['id'];

        try {

            $stmt = $this->dbconn->prepare("SELECT * FROM centrifuge WHERE id = ?");
            $stmt->execute(array($uid));
            return $stmt->fetchAll();
        }
```

So, obvious from all the subjects I read, this is dangerous to SQL injection. But how do I use this code with prepared statements? I can't seem to get it work with the id placeholder.

Comment: _So obviously this is dangerous_ No its not!!! You have already decided to use parpared, parameterised and bound queries. Maybe you should read all those subjects again

Comment: @RiggsFolly Ok, sorry for that. I thought when you click a link and the URL look like this for example: ...Views/user_centrifuge.php?id=26 , which I'm getting now, it was supposed dangerous.

Comment: It would be if you were doing `"SELECT * FROM centrifuge WHERE id = $id"` but not if you are preparing and binding

Comment: For the reasons RiggsFolly mentioned it isn't. As mentioned in some of the answers you may do some additional checking to make sure it is an integer if that is what you expect it to be.

Comment: Well to be honest you SHOULD really do a bit of a sanity check on what is actually being sent to you from anywhere outside your control, so the cast to int would be a good idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks good as is. You could additionally cast your input var to INT.

```
(int)$_GET['id'] or intval($_GET['id'])
```